# Node: building from source vs binary distribution

Tags: node.js

I have downloaded node 0.10.31 source and built on my Linux machine using same steps mentioned in wiki. The source is just as it is and no changes made at all. The build is successful but when I compare bin/node file size with the one from binary downloaded there is around 900kb difference (built from source is bigger).

What is the reason?

Did I miss any optimizer or special config? Actually I wanted to use locally build node (after some change) in production. I just don't want to miss some settings here.

My environment:

```
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)

Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 21 2013, 10:50:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2

LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
Release:        6.5
Codename:       Santiago
```

Note: Already posted in node.js groups, sorry for the cross post.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try and strip out debugging symbols.  E.g.,

```
$ strip node
```

[Debugging symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_symbol) are pieces of information embedded in an object file, and useful for debugging purposes.  Unfortunately, they take up space in the file, so if you do not plan debugging the `node` interpreter itself you could get rid of them.

Moreover, please check out [`strip`'s manual page](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.24/binutils/strip.html#strip) for a full list of choices when discarding symbols from object files.

Comment: Tried with 'strip -g node', now it is coming less than binary distribution. Not sure if it is ok. Actually was looking for some special make targets, but couldn't find one which comes closer to binary.

Comment: Did you try `make install-strip`?

Comment: I didn't find any target like install-strip. Which version of node it is supported?

Comment: `install-strip` should be the standard target for stripping the executables while installing them (cf. the GNU Coding Standards).  Unfortunately, I do not know if the source distribution of node complies with this.